# Packages in Eclipse/CDT

Tags: eclipse, package, projects, eclipse-cdt

Is it possible in Eclipse to have some kind of packages (sets of projects) when using CDT projects?

We have separated our software in such packages and use VS2005 with .sln files for the Windows parts.
At the moment I see only two ways to manage the projects in Eclipse:

- Put all together into a single workspace and loose the package ordering
- Use separate workspaces (one per package) and store my custom key/syntax/... settings in each workspace (and keep them synchronous!)

The main reason for separating the projects is that you do not need to compile (or check if compilation is needed which also takes a while) all base projects if you are working in a depending package.

I would appreciate a third solution without the disadvantages of my two current solutions :-)

Rüdiger

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at Eclipse's **[working sets](http://help.eclipse.org/ganymede/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/concepts/cworkset.htm)** feature for grouping and managing your projects.

You can create working sets from the **Window** → **Working Sets** → **Edit...** menu. Once you've done that click the triangle button in your project listing view (either your *Project Explorer* or *C/C++ Projects* view) and change the **Top Level Elements** option to be working sets instead of projects. From here you can then drag and drop your projects from the *Other Projects* folder in your project listing into the working sets you have defined. From there you can then open or close all the projects contained in a working set by right clicking on the the working set and selecting **Open Project** or **Close Project**.

I'm not entirely sure if that alone will address your situation, but it did the trick to help me manage all my Java projects in a single Eclipse workspace.

Comment: Sounds good! I will test it as soon as I have time for it!
(I once saw the working sets but didn't get a hand on them but maybe with your tips...)

Comment: I didn't found them in the menu you mentioned but by using the triangle button and "Select WorkingSets" I was able not only to select them but also to create them and assign projects.